# If my question is migrated to meta or SU and closed in SO then should i delete those questions from SO?

Tags: support

If my question is migrated to meta or SU and closed in SO then should i delete those questions from SO?

and if i delete those moved , unanswered, or answer not selected questions

then would it effect to my accept rate?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>(Just to keep this from being bumped by Community again)</sub>

You can't. Migrated questions are locked.

You can, however, flag them and request a moderator to delete them.

**But**, since all the answers are deleted from the original site when a question is migrated, the question won't count in your accept rate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, deleting unanswered questions does affect your accept-rate.

But if the question has been migrated, it doesn't really make sense to keep it on a site it doesn't belong to.. (unless you want some extra traffic :P)

Comment: so is it good to delete my silly and unanswered and answer not needed now like questions.? will it increase my accept rate?

Comment: I deleted some of my old questions on SO today - Yes, it increased my accept-rate.